# Draw streamlines in python fails with unequally spaced x,y values

Tags: python

In my python code below, I am able to plot relative humidity and wind barbs. I  would like to add streamlines to the plot. This is the only part which does not work, the error being that x and y are not equally spaced.
Being not very conversant in python and in numpy I have tried to guess with the following lines

```
 x, y = m(LON[Time_Index],LAT[Time_Index]) #conversion to map projection
```

see edit in the main code.

All the above do not work (apart from conversion to map projection).
With the two lines of either np.arange() or np.linspace(), I get the error: "IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed".
With mesgrid, I get a "WARNING: x coordinate not montonically increasing" and then on the line with im = m.contourf(x,y,RH[Time_Index,Height_Index],cmap=plt.cm.BrBG) "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (78,129) (10062,10062)"

The retrieval of humidity and wind data form the file is done in a separate file, imported into the script. This is not included here, for reasons of space.
I would appreciate assistance on how to make x,y evenly spaced
So far my search for any example of wind streamlines on map plots in python has yielded nothing.

```
#Import libraries      
##################
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from read_wrf import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import shapefile as shp

#Read in the file using the read_wrf script
###########################################
filename = './wrfout_d01_2022-09-28_00:00:00'
LAT,LON,RH,U,V = main(filename)

# Get the times from the model
# The Pressure levels that are used in the interpolation function
# To add pressure levels need to first do so in the read_wrf script
###################################################################
TIMES = get_wrf_var('Times',filename)
PLevels = np.array([1000,850,700,500,300,200])

#Use basemap to plot land or use the landmask
#################################
#LM = get_wrf_var('LANDMASK',filename)

#Calculate wind speed magnitude
#################################
WSPD = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

#Loop over times, and pressure levels
#####################################
for Time_Index,T in enumerate(TIMES):
    for Height_Index,H in enumerate(PLevels):

    #Plot RH with barbs
    ####################
    #Declare the figure
    ###################
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    #define map extent
    ###################
    lllon,lllat,urlon,urlat = 15.63819,-34.30278,36.36181,-23.41068
    
    #Set up Basemap instance
    #########################
    m = Basemap(
    projection = 'merc', \
    llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, \
    urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat, resolution='h')
        
    #Read shapefile
    ###############
    m.readshapefile('/home/zmumba/DA/SCRIPTS/06_Utility_Files/Shapefiles/Lesotho/lso_admbnda_adm1_FAO_MLGCA_2019', 'lso_admbnda_adm1_FAO_MLGCA_2019')

    # Add Coastlines, States, and Country Boundaries
    ################################################
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color = 'white')
    m.drawcountries(
    linewidth=1.25, linestyle='solid', color='#000073',
    antialiased=True,
    ax=ax, zorder=3)
       
    # Add Grid Lines
    ################
    # draw parallels
    ################
    parallels = np.arange(-35., -25., 5.)
    m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],color = '0.25',
    linewidth = 0.5,fontsize=10)
    m.drawlsmask(land_color='coral',ocean_color='aqua',lakes=True)

    # draw meridians
    ################
    meridians = np.arange(15., 35., 5.)
    m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],color = 'black',
    linewidth = 0.5,fontsize=10)

    #compute map proj coordinates
    #############################
    x, y = m(LON[Time_Index],LAT[Time_Index])

    #x = np.arange(-35., -25., 5.)
    #y = np.arange(15., 35., 5.)

    #x = np.linspace(-35., -25.,num=10)
    #y = np.linspace(15., 35., num=10)

    #X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    ###################################
    clev = np.arange(0,110,5)

    #Plot the RH at the specified pressure level and time
    #####################################################
    im = m.contourf(X,Y,RH[Time_Index,Height_Index],clev,cmap=plt.cm.BrBG)

    #Draw wind barbs
    ################
    m.barbs(X[::10,::10],Y[::10,::10],U[Time_Index,Height_Index,::10,::10],V[Time_Index,Height_Index,::10,::10],sizes=dict(emptybarb=0.25, spacing=.1, height=0.3), flip_barb=True, color='r')
    
    #Draw streamlines
    #################
#Code for preparing streamline plot
##########################################################
speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2                                                                                      
n,p=U[Time_Index,Height_Index].shape[1],U[Time_Index,Height_Index].shape[0]
x1 = np.linspace(np.nanmin(x), np.nanmax(x), n)
y1 = np.linspace(np.nanmin(y), np.nanmax(y), p)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)

#Draw the streamlines
m.streamplot(xi,yi,U[Time_Index,Height_Index],V[Time_Index,Height_Index],linewidth=1.,color='blue',density=2.5)

    
    # Add Colorbar
    #################
    cbar = m.colorbar(im)

    #save image and display
    #######################
    plt.savefig("V%s_T+%sH.png" %(H,vt),bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your time looking at my code. I managed to solve my problem. Now streamlines can be drawn with the code I have added in the edit.

Comment: I need to find out where the solution is given. Could you please identify it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered by an edit of 05/09/2022